# Javascript animation with

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm attempting to get certain items to animate from one location to a new one on a click of the appropriate button. Even though I used fixed positions and have javascript to set the location before the animation, things still go off the page before to the end point.

Firefox and Webkit browsers have had different errors on and off and I can't find a solid solution to this, could anyone help me out with this?

```
$(function(){
    $("#nav li").click(function() {
        $("#nav").css({
            'left' : $(this).position().left + 'px',
            'top' : $(this).position().top + 'px'
        })
        .animate({
             'margin-top' : '-175px',
              'margin-left' : '0px',
            'left' : '10px',
            'top' : '50%',
            'height' : '370px',
            'width' : '70px'
        }, 500, 'swing');

        $("#name").css({
            'top': $(this).position().top + 'px'
        })
        .animate({
            'top' : '100px'
        } , 500, 'swing');
    });

    $("#buttona").click(function() {
        $("#a").animate({
            'opacity' : '1' ,
            'top' : '50%',
             'margin-top' : '-200px'
            }, 500, 'swing');
    });

});
```

Comment: On safari I'm not seeing an error, and aside from some slow loading (prolly my internet) it seems to work fine.

Comment: The squares are supposed to animate directly from their loading point to the side of the page, not flash to the top left and then down and the title should go directly up

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `#nav li#a` and `.set#a` worries me. IDs must be unique, so it never makes sense to use more than just an ID in a selector. This is almost certainly the cause of your animation issues.

Comment: just fixed some things up, thanks for pointing that out!

updated the code in the original post, still acting funky :/